# Spring Data MongoDB regex query on array

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

My Document:

```
@Document
public class Box {
    @Id
    String id;

    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("I'm Item1", "item2", "i am Item3");
}
```

I'd like the user to be able to filter box documents by items.
The user can provide 2 lists, includedItems and excludedItems.
How can i build a query with regex search on the same array, the values should be queried with `AND` instead of an `OR` (this is why I've tried `all`)?

Here is what I've tried which doesn't work:

```
// This is the user input
List<String> includedItems = Arrays.asList("item1", "tem2");
List<String> excludedItems = Arrays.asList("Item3");

// Here I build the query according to the user input
Query q = new Query();
Criteria includeCriteria = Criteria.where("items").all(Pattern.compile("^(?!" + String.join("|", includedItems) + ")"));
Criteria excludeCriteria = Criteria.where("items").nin(Pattern.compile("^(?!" + String.join("|", excludedItems) + ")"));
if (includeCriteria != null && excludeCriteria != null) {
    Criteria andCriteria = new Criteria().andOperator(includeCriteria, excludeCriteria);
    q.addCriteria(andCriteria);
} else {
    if (includeCriteria != null) {
        q.addCriteria(includeCriteria);
    }
    if (excludeCriteria != null) {
        q.addCriteria(excludeCriteria);
    }
}
```